# how to assign noise to sine wave using matlab or i have to use the command?

Tags: matlab, command, noise, trigonometry

i have assignment that i have to print a pure sine wave & add some noise to it & print another copy, i know that i can get pure sine wave using matlab/simulink but how can i add noise to it? is there away to implement it using simulink part of matlab or i have to use the commands, i donnt know too much about commands in matlab so i implemented it using simulink also the output of the pure sine wave block doesn't appear like pure sine wave so what's the problem? thanks. 
[image]

Comment: Your question ("What's the problem?") is too general and it does not seem like you've put much effort into helping yourself. Your issues could easily be solved by going through a basic MATLAB tutorial. Additionally, this is a site for programming questions but you seem to want to avoid any actual programming and just use the simulink gui.

Comment: yes i prefer simulink work, cuz i'm familiar with simulink which is not the case with matlab command

Comment: To help you out a bit more, the "problem" above is that your resolution is quite low. I'm not familiar with simulink, but you adjust the number of points and do what you need very easily with the MATLAB commands `linspace`, `sin`, `awgn`, and `plot`. I'd suggest reading the documentation and examples for those. MATLAB's documentation is very good and should be plenty to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

You can add white noise to any waveform by using the built in function `awgn`.

Comment: can you explain more plz ?

Answer (score 0):

both `awgn` and `wgn` functions work. but you'd better know what SNR is needed.